# onFling not working

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, onfling

I have a `ViewPager` which holds a `RecyclerView` I add a `OnTouchListener` to an image view inside the `RecyclerView`'s item, trying to detect touches using `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` but I can't get the `onFling` events. I suspect it's happening because either the `RecyclerView` or the `ViewPager` catching the motion event. How do I fix it?
 My code (though it's pretty simple):

```
public class MyClickListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

public MyClickListener(){

}

@Override
public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onShowPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("aaa", "show press");
}

@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
    Log.d("aaa", "tapup");
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX,
        float distanceY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("aaa", "scroll");
    return false;
}

@Override
public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("aaa", "long press");
}

@Override
public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
        float velocityY) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.d("aaa", "fling");
    return false;
}
```

setting the oun touch:

```
public VoiceItemHolder(View view, GestureDetector.OnGestureListener listener) {
    super(view); 

    icon = (CircleButton) view.findViewById(R.id.icon_iv);
    touchListener = new GestureDetectorCompat(view.getContext(), listener);

    icon.setOnTouchListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (touchListener != null)
        touchListener.onTouchEvent(event);
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Feeling a bit awkward to answer my own question :)
If you have a view in a view group and you want to get `onFling`'s on the inner view you should override the `onInterceptTouchEvent` of the view group and return `false`